# How many test cases can I run if I'm using domain testing?

Tags: test-design, coverage, test-techniques, code

I'd like to understand what is domain testing, and how do we use it to calculate coverage (if possible)? 
My question is imagine I have 3 loops in series and I'm using domain testing approach how many test cases are necessary to achieve path coverage ?

```
Y=12
Z=2
   for (x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
      if (something) {
          break;
      }
      ...
   }
for (x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
      Y=X+2
      ...
   }
for (x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
     Z=10+Z
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain testing is an umbrella term for Equivalent partition and boundary value analysis. Here, we try to cover all the available behaviours of a system by using the least number of inputs. Here domain means each partition that is created.

**Equivalent partition** means we divide the inputs into different partitions, here each partition means input value range for which the behaviour of the system is identical (means remains the same)

**Boundary value analysis** means the boundary values of the partitions we found eg if 1 to 5 is a partition then 1 and 5.

*For example, consider a system that takes all non zero positive numbers less than 10.*

Here the Equivalent partition would be:

```
**Invalid**: -infinity to 0
**Valid**:    1 to 10
**Invalid**:  11 to +infinity
```

And the boundary values would be :

```
0,1,10,11
```

So to test this system you can use all the identified boundary values and any, one value from each partition eg `-10,5,16`

> For your given code:

Unless there is a defined behaviour difference for each value of y and z you cannot create a partition table.

There should be clear stating of valid and invalid values for these fields.

From a normal test perspective as there are 3 for loop and, only one for-loop has a condition. you could get 100 % coverage by using two inputs (one to make something false and one to make something true )

As there is no other condition, all the codes will get executed